# About CSS priority level of selector

Tags: html, css

Recently, I am studying CSS priority level of selector according to the page: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector, I have one problem:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.see-me,
ul li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* [0,0,0,2] */

ul li {
  background: yellow; color: red;
}
/* [0,0,10,0] */

.see-me {
  background: gray; color: blue;

}
```

```html
<div class="see-me">
  <ul>
    <li>.see-me has higher priority level [0,0,10,0], so why is font color not blue, but red ?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

font color should be blue, but it is red ! here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8eeprjdf/2/)

Comment: `.see-me` is grey it's just hidden by the `li`. Inspect the HTML and you'll see.

Comment: but, if you put ul li { background: yellow; color: red; } and .see-me { background: gray; color: blue; } you will see, the font color also did not changed!

Comment: What color do you think it should be?

Comment: it should be blue accord to w3c

Comment: You're misunderstanding how CSS selectors work. If you put the .see-me class on the li instead of the div, then you'd see that.

Comment: I know your meaning, but if so, why need to count selector's number according to w3c site? if  count selector's number can not applied to all selector, why we need to study it ?

Comment: in fact, CSS priority level of selector is not very usful,  this is my conclusion.. ^^  thanks!

Comment: CSS priority level of selector should base on the same tag. if so, the nearest one will have higher level, good luck!

Comment: oh...  got, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The see-me class does in fact have a gray background. Since the ul element is a child of the div with the see-me class it is drawn on top of it.

Comment: but, if you put ul li { background: yellow; color: red; } and .see-me { background: gray; color: blue; } you will see, the font color also did not changed!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8eeprjdf/2/ here is my update..  if so, is it not belongs to CSS priority level of selector ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you couldn't see see-me!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.see-me,
ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* [0,0,0,2] */

ul li {
  background: yellow;
}
/* [0,0,10,0] */

.see-me {
  height:300px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="see-me">
  <ul>
    <li>.see-me has higher priority level [0,0,10,0], so why is background not gray, but yellow ?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```